# How to import System.Net.Mail

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I'm typing "Imports System.Net.Mail" but it says that "namespace or type 'Mail' for the imports 'System.Net.mail' cannot be found".
I've already added in the references "system.web.dll" and "system.dll".

What else do I need to use the namespace System.Net.Mail?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:**

You will need to install .net version 2 ( or better, 3.5 sp1 ). And you will have to upgrade to visual studio 2005 or 2008.

**Update 1:**

[System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) is new to .net framework 2. If you have to use .net 1.1 then you have to use: [System.Web.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.aspx)

**Update 0:**

Is .net framework 2 installed on your computer?
Which version of visual studio are you using?